# Putting forest trees in table cells

Tags: tables, spacing, forest, alignment

I would like to put a forest tree in each cell of the first column of a table. There are some issues when I do this: The spacing is too tight, and the numbers in the rest of the table go to the bottom. I don't really know enough about how to use `forest` to figure out how to add spacing around it, and I also don't know how it interacts with latex tables. Here's what it looks like right now:

[image: trees in table]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
    \text{Tree} & N_L(T) & \frac{1}{3}N(T) \\\hline
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
      []
    \end{forest}
                & 1      & \frac{1}{3}     \\\hline
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
      [[,no edge, draw=none][]]
    \end{forest}
                & 1      & \frac{2}{3}     \\\hline
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
      [[][,no edge, draw=none]]
    \end{forest}
                & 1      & \frac{2}{3}     \\\hline
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
      [[][]]
    \end{forest}
                & 2      & 1               \\\hline
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so folks here can compile the whole document and test it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proposal.

1. The `forest`s are wrapped into `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` to vertically center them.
2. `forest` is based on Ti*k*Z, and in the equation, i.e. locally, every `tikzpicture`'s bounding box is increased. This allows one to obtain a finer control of the padding than with the standard methods like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}` or `\\[...]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at end picture={%
\path (current bounding box.north)  +(0,1ex) (current bounding box.south) +(0,-1ex);}}}
    \begin{array}{|c|c|c|}\hline
        \text{Tree} & N_L(T) & \frac{1}{3}N(T) \\\hline
        \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
        for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
        []      
        \end{forest}}}
                    & 1      & \frac{1}{3}     \\\hline
        \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
        for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
        [[,no edge, draw=none][]]
        \end{forest}}}
                    & 1      & \frac{2}{3}     \\\hline
        \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
        for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
        [[][,no edge, draw=none]]
        \end{forest}}}
                    & 1      & \frac{2}{3}     \\\hline
        \vcenter{\hbox{\begin{forest}
        for tree={ grow=south, circle, draw, minimum size=3ex, inner sep=1pt, s sep=3mm }
        [[][]]
        \end{forest}}}
                    & 2      & 1               \\\hline
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this worked beautifully thanks. Can you explain how you got this result?

Comment: @nakamin You're welcome!  I tried to do so in items 1 and 2. I'll be happy to extend the explanation if you give me a hint what I should explain more.

Comment: Oh I some how didn't notice those, that explains it fine thanks.